# Node.js await postgresql error

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, async-await, node-postgres

I use express and PostgreSql.

My Project Folder :

```
-Model
    -Visitor.js
-app.js
```

I have connected postgresql with pg and i've tested with a query. It's running well. But, there is a query on Visitor.js file.

```
var visitor = function() {
    this.add = function() {
        var ret = false;
        db.query({text: 'INSERT INTO visitor(visitorid, data, status) VALUES($1, $2, $3)', values:[id, JSON.stringify(data), "1"]}, function (err, response) {
            if(!err) {
                ret = true;
            }
        });
        return ret;
    }
}
```

This query always inserts a row in my table but returns false. This function should wait query to end. How can i do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You should await on a promise

```
this.add = function() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db.query({text: 'INSERT INTO visitor(visitorid, data, status) VALUES($1, $2, $3)', values:[id, JSON.stringify(data), "1"]}, function (err, response) {
            if(!err)
                resolve(response)
            else
                reject(err)
        });
    })        
}
```

Then you can await on visitor.add function

**EDIT**
If you are using the [pg](https://node-postgres.com/) library: as shown in [Getting Started](https://node-postgres.com/#getting-started), you can directly await on the client.query function as it returns a Promise when you don't provide a callback

```
const { Client } = require('pg')
const client = new Client()

await client.connect()

const res = await client.query('SELECT $1::text as message', ['Hello world!'])
console.log(res.rows[0].message) // Hello world!
await client.end()
```

Comment: i have tried await, again

await client.connect();

Then i am retrieving an error :

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: You can await only inside async functions. Search on google, every async/await tutorial explains this